# Getting AndroidRuntime exceptions from LogCat and write to a file

Tags: android, android-logcat

When I navigate to my `platform-tools` folder under the android-sdk folder, I'm able to perform some operation so I can get outputs from `LogCat`

Like this command for instance

```
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:E
```

This will list out messages with the tag `AndroidRuntime`. To test this I removed the `super.onResume()` in my `onResume` method, and the output would look something like this in my commandline window in win7:

[image]

So far so good, This is the type of information I want to log. I have a method in my application which looks like this:

```
public class LogCatReader {

    // constants
    private static final String CR = "\r\n";
    private static final String END_OF_DATE_TIME = "): ";
    private static final int DEFAULT_SEARCH_START_INDEX = 0;

    // member variables
    private StringBuilder mLog;
    private LogThread mLogThread = null;
    private String mLastLogReadToken = "";
    private String mLogCommand = "";
    private String mProcess = "";
    private int mStringCapacity;
    private File mFileTarget = null;


    // constructor
    public LogCatReader(String command, int capacity, String process) {
        mLogCommand = command;
        mStringCapacity = capacity;
        mProcess = process;
    }

    // returns complete logcat buffer
    // note: takes about 1.5sec to finish
    synchronized public StringBuilder getLogComplete() {
        try {
            // capacity should be about 25% bigger than buffer size since the
            // buffer is compressed
            mLog = new StringBuilder(mStringCapacity);

            // command to capture log
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mLogCommand);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // append() is costly if capacity needs to be increased, be sure
                // to reserve enough in the first place
                mLog.append(line + CR);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return mLog;
    }

    public String getLogUpdatesOnly() {
        String strReturn = "";

        StringBuilder sbLog = getLogComplete();

        try {
            int iStartindex = DEFAULT_SEARCH_START_INDEX;

            // if there exists a token from a previous search then use that
            if (mLastLogReadToken.length() > 0) {
                iStartindex = sbLog.indexOf(mLastLogReadToken);

                // if string not found then start at beginning
                if (iStartindex == -1) {
                    // start search at beginning of log
                    iStartindex = DEFAULT_SEARCH_START_INDEX;
                }
            }

            int iEndindex = sbLog.length();

            // if token is found then move index to the next line
            if (iStartindex > DEFAULT_SEARCH_START_INDEX) {
                iStartindex = sbLog.indexOf(CR, iStartindex);

                if (iStartindex != -1) {
                    iStartindex += CR.length();
                } else {
                    // return an empty string
                    iStartindex = iEndindex;
                }
            }

            // grab the data between the start and end indices
            strReturn = sbLog.substring(iStartindex, iEndindex);

            // grab date/time token for next search
            iStartindex = sbLog.lastIndexOf(END_OF_DATE_TIME);

            if (iStartindex != -1) {
                iEndindex = iStartindex;
                iStartindex = sbLog.lastIndexOf(CR, iEndindex);
                iStartindex += CR.length();

                if (iStartindex == -1) {
                    // read from beginning
                    iStartindex = 0;
                }

                mLastLogReadToken = sbLog.substring(iStartindex, iEndindex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            strReturn = "";
        }

        return strReturn;
    }

    public void startPeriodicLogCatReader(int timePeriod, String logfilename) {
        if (mLogThread == null) {
            mLogThread = new LogThread(timePeriod, logfilename);
            mLogThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopPeriodicLogCatReader() {
        if (mLogThread != null) {
            mLogThread.interrupt();
            mLogThread = null;
        }
    }

    private class LogThread extends Thread {
        private boolean mInterrupted;
        private int mTimePeriod;// in seconds
        private String mLogref;
        private BufferedWriter mBuffWriter = null;
        public boolean mPauseLogCollection = false;

        // constructor: logfilename is optional - pass null to not use
        public LogThread(int timePeriod, String logfilename) {
            mTimePeriod = timePeriod;

            if (logfilename != null) {
                File fLogFolder = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SteriaFITMobile/CoreLogging");
                if (fLogFolder.exists() == false) {
                    if (fLogFolder.mkdirs() == false) {
                        Log.e("LogCatReader",
                                "Could not create "
                                        + fLogFolder.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }

                mFileTarget = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SteriaFITMobile/CoreLogging",
                        logfilename);

                if (mFileTarget.exists() == false) {
                    try {
                        // file doesn't yet exist - create a fresh one !
                        mFileTarget.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        mFileTarget = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            mInterrupted = true;
            super.interrupt();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            // initialization
            mInterrupted = false;

            // set up storage
            if (mFileTarget != null) {
                try {
                    mBuffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                            mFileTarget, true), 10240);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            while ((mInterrupted == false) && (mBuffWriter != null)) {
                if (mPauseLogCollection == false) {
                    // read log updates
                    mLogref = mProcess + ": " + getLogUpdatesOnly();

                    // save log updates to file
                    try {
                        mBuffWriter.append(mLogref);
                        mBuffWriter.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (!mInterrupted) {
                    try {
                        sleep(mTimePeriod * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mBuffWriter != null) {
                try {
                    mBuffWriter.close();
                    mBuffWriter = null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }// end of inner class
}// end of outer class
```

This methods takes three parameters, the command, a capacity and a processName(ActivityName).

This methods just executes the `command parameter` to a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` method call, and saves it to a `.txt` file on the sdcard. My problem is that the command

```
adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:E
```

Works in windows, but not on the android phone.

What I want to achieve is to log out this type of AndroidRuntime errors to a logfile on the SDCard. I'm only interested in AndroidRuntime Errors which causes my application to perform an ANR.

Some of you might suggest that I only create my own `Log.d, Log.e, Log.v` and writes them to a file, but I doesn't want that..

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: So explain why you wouldn't just use a custom tag to output logcat errors?  Seems like instead of trying to recreate the wheel, you should use the existing functionality.

Comment: On an Android phone, you should just use the `logcat` command.

Comment: @Booger I'm not quite sure if there is any other way to log out the AndroidRuntime exceptions, without doing it inside a `Try/Catch`. In my example, how should I log that I forgot the `super.onPause`?

Comment: maybe you should use something like an ACRA or bugsense.com

Answer (score 1):

in command i'm use to do adb logcat >> folder/filename.txt 
Maybe that format can help you